# container cannnot connect to service from another container

Tags: networking, docker, postgresql, containers, docker-compose

I have the following containers running:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
b02d801f9aa3        development_mongo      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:50001->27017/tcp                           compose_mongo
2903bb830ea7        development_postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:50000->5432/tcp                            compose_postgres
6ce3fe015a8f        development_elastic    "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   7 hours ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:50002->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50003->9300/tcp   compose_elastic
```

When I create/run a Docker container that has `python manage.py makemigrations` as entrypoint, the Django app can't connect to the Postgres container:

```
 $ docker run --name test1 repo/myapp:stage_1605191501

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 50000?
```

Why it cannot connect, since that Postgres port is already exposed to the host? What am I missing?

Comment: Please show your docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I already got the problem, Michael: different networks. Some containers using a custom network and other container connected only to default bridge. I posted the answer below. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all `compose_*` containers, are attached to a different Docker Network, as well as `test1`, is associated to another network.

```
$ docker network inspect development_default | grep 'Name\|IPv4'
    "Name": "development_default",
            "Name": "compose_postgres",
            "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
            "Name": "compose_elastic",
            "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
            "Name": "compose_mongo",
            "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
```

These containers were created through Docker Compose, without specifying a custom network. If no custom network is defined on your Docker Compose file, docker will create a custom network which uses the name of the directory from were you have your build environment. That's why the *development*, name of the directory which was holding the files for generating these containers, was used when creating a `development_default` network for them.

- When executed the command `$ docker run --name test1 repo/myapp:stage_1605191501`, no `--network` was specified, so `test1` will be associated to the default `bridge` network.
- `compose_postgres` has 5432 port exposed to the host network and it is associated to `development_default` network (172.20.0.0/16).

**Answer (steps):**

1. provide static IP for `compose_postgres`
2. define this IP for the Django app definitions, inside the image of `test1`, in order to provide  connection from the app to `compose_postgres` database
3. define `development_default` as the `--network` for `test1` when running `docker run`

For further reference:

- [Docker Compose (define IP for container/service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose)
- [Docker Container Network (concept)](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/)
- [Docker Network (connect container to network)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/)
- [Docket Network (command reference)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/)

Comment: You don't need the `compose_` part, that's the project name in compose which can change. Set it to `postgres`, `elastic`, and `mongo` for the hostnames instead. You'll see network aliases configured for these when deploying your project in compose.